# XStream java.util.Map field marshalling

Tags: java, xstream

I would like to use a custom converter for an object in xstream, but default to the default behavior for some fields.

unfortunately, when writing a field like map in TestObject, xstream does not write the surrounding `<map>...</map>` tags.

```
public static class TestObject {
    public Map map;
    public Object custom;
}
protected static XStream stream = new XStream();
protected static Converter TestObjectConverter = new Converter() {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type == TestObject.class;
    }
    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        TestObject obj = (TestObject)source;
        context.convertAnother(obj.map);
    }
};
@Override
protected void runApp() throws Exception {
    stream.registerConverter(TestObjectConverter);
    TestObject obj = new TestObject();
    obj.map = new HashMap();
    obj.map.put(1, "asdf");
    obj.map.put(2, "qwerty");
    String xml = stream.toXML(obj);
    return;
};
```

essentially i am looking to replicate the default behavior for some fields in TestObject, but using custom converters for others. What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

to get the default behavior, make sure your `UnmarshallingContext` is a `AbstractReferenceMarshaller`, and call `context.start(object, context)`.